# ambiguous call to function using initializer_list in VS2013

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, initializer-list

I have the following example code. It compiles on clang but it doesn't on Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void f(const pair<string, string>& p)
{
    cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << endl;
}

void f(initializer_list<pair<string, string> > ps) {
    for (auto p : ps) f(p);
}

int main()
{
    f({ "2", "3" });
    f({ { "2", "3" }, { "3", "4" } });
}
```

The second call to f fails to compile with:

```
1error C2668: 'f' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
could be 'void f(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>)'
or       'void f(const std::pair<std::string,std::string> &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(initializer-list)'
```

If I use pairs of int instead of pairs of string it does work fine.

Is anybody aware of a problem like this in Visual Studio? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm almost sure I've seen something like this in a bug report..

Comment: I suspect the second call is being interpreted as `f(pair(string("2", "3"), string("3, 4")))`, using the constructor of `std::string` that takes a pair of iterators (`const char*` pointers are valid iterators), in addition to "initializer list of pairs" interpretation. Off the top of my head, I can't say whether such an interpretation is legal.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik is there an initializer list ctor for `pair`?

Comment: @Yakk: `std::pair` is an aggregate; this is why brace-initializer works for it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `std::pair` is not an aggregate - it's got plenty of user-provided constructors.

Comment: @T.C. Of course. Don't know what I was thinking. The brace-initializer simply invokes a plain old two-parameter constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`{ { "2", "3" }, { "3", "4" } }` may be used to initialize either a `initializer_list<pair<string, string> >` or a `pair<string, string>`, in the second case by calling the two-iterator constructor of `std::string` (and causing UB in the process). Both are list-initialization sequences. Both invoke a user-defined conversion.

§13.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank]/p3:

> List-initialization sequence L1 is a better conversion sequence than
>   list-initialization sequence L2 if:
>
> - L1 converts to `std::initializer_list<X>` for some `X` and L2 does not [...]

There's no ambiguity. `void f(initializer_list<pair<string, string> > ps);` should be unambiguously selected.